# Even though I create the data in Entities I created with Typeorm as "nullable: false", I can save it as "null"

Tags: mongodb, typescript, typeorm

Edit: when I use sqlite as database, it works fine. I think it's all about typeorm-mongodb integration

First of all, sorry for grammar mistakes

i have an entity like this

```
@Entity()
export class Entity extends BaseEntity {
    @PrimaryColumn({ unique: true })
    id: string;

    @ObjectIdColumn()
    _id: ObjectID;

    @Column({ nullable: false, default: 0 })
    premium: number;

    @CreateDateColumn({ type: "timestamp" })
    createdAt: number;

    @UpdateDateColumn({ type: "timestamp" })
    updatedAt: number;
}
```

but when I try to  create a data like this, it saves but it shouldn't

```
const model = Entity.create();
await <Typeorm.Connection>.mongoManager.save(model);
```

In short, "null" can be saved even if I say "@PrimaryColumn()" or do "nullable: false"

thanks for all helps :3

Comment: What do you mean by "can be saved"? Do you mean that it is actually persisted or that TypeScript doesn't raise an error?

Comment: i mean it saves but it doesn't throws any error

here is the output: https://imgur.com/aJoOmSE

Comment: So the id is being auto generated.

Comment: If I don't specify the "id" value and the "premium" value, it only saves the default data "_id", "createdAt" and "updatedAt" but it should give an error

Comment: Well, `premium` has a default value, so it absolutely _should_ work. Regarding `_id`, omitting it implies that you are inserting a new record rather than saving an existing record.

Comment: I'm talking about that too. `premium` should default to` 0` but it doesn't save anything

Comment: I even tried saving the `premium` value as `null` and it saved it but it shouldn't. Here is the output: https://imgur.com/piiOtzn

Comment: Post all that information in the question.

Comment: this is my guildEntity.ts file: https://hasteb.in/padexuma.coffeescript When I run the `fetch` function here, it has to give the existing data, otherwise it should create new data and give that data. generates data, but the "premium" value, "guildID" value etc. not saved. Blank data is saved to database